# filter by Id of a Vertex

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am trying to use a filter step to filter vertices by id, but unsure of how to do this.

Here is roughly what I am trying to do.

```
g.V().has(label, 'Users').filter(id().is(eq("Users:77287168:1051")))
g.V().has(label, 'Users').filter(id().is("Users:77287168:1051"))
```

Both of the above always return 0 records. However

```
g.V().has(label, 'Users').filter(hasId("Users:77287168:1051"))
```

This works as intended and I am getting the a User with the given id.

Again the above is only representational and I would just like to know how/what would it take to do an `id()` comparison inside my filter function. For instance I am expecting my traversal argument to filter to traverse vertices and I would like to compare it against the current traversal's vertex id.

Comment: it's possible that `is()` might not be optimizing properly in the traversal. what version of DSE are you using?

Comment: @stephenmallette The version is DSE 5.1.3. I didn't quite understand is() not being optimized.

Comment: @stephenmallette : Some more observation on the `is`. `g.V().has(label, 'Users').filter(label().is('Users')` works. But `userId = g.V("Users:77287168:1051").id(); g.V().has(label, 'Users').filter(label().is(userId))` didn't work and returned 0 results.

Comment: i just meant it is likely a bug in DSE Graph. DSE Graph is not recognizing the use of `is()` in that context to use the specified id as a vertex lookup.

Comment: @stephenmallette: Hi, Are there any workarounds ? In the filter step, If I want to do use id() what are the options available ?

Comment: There could be, but you'd need to adjust your question to explain more of what you are doing. Given your example, `hasId()` seems to be the best workaround.

Comment: I have a code to search for vertices say `Users` and then would like to filter them further based on current user's access privileges. `g.V().has(label, 'Users').filter(V('currentUserId).out('user_groups').hasId(id()))`. `user_group` in that query is only representational, in my eventual workflow, it will be a longer traversal

Comment: Based on what you've said there, I don't think you really have a need for use of `hasId()` in the way you are using it. Seems like your the traversal in your comment above simplifies to just: `g.V('currentUserId').out('user_groups').hasId('someGroupId')` I know you say your actual traversal will be much more complex but if you can't provide some minimal example of what you are trying to do that doesn't easily simplify to a different traversal that won't have the problem you're facing, I don't think I can be of much help. fwiw, DSE Graph engineers are looking at the actual problems with `is()`